# merging my local branch with remote master

Tags: git, merge

I am new to git. I am working on a codebase with a team.
The status of my remote repository is:

```
git remote show origin                                # show the status
Remote branches:
....
                     master                             tracked
                     branch_to_be_merged                 tracked
...
Local branches configured for git pull:
master                                                 merges with remote master
branch_to_be_merged                                      merges with remote branch_to_be_merged      

Local refs configured for git push:
master                                                 pushes to master
branch_to_be_merged                                       pushes to  branch_to_be_merged
```

I have been working on a feature  on `branch_to_be_merged`, while `master` was actively developed.
Now I need to make my feature available to the public, and I would be merging using the following series of git commands.

Is the following correct?

```
git fetch origin                #make sure I am updated with latest remote changes
git checkout -b branch_to_be_merged   # the currently checked out branch is the one of interest
git branch                      # check I am on the branch I would like to merge later (it should now show *branch_to_be_merged)
git pull origin master           # apply the latest remote changes to my local branch_to_be_merged [I EXPECT CONFLICTS HERE]
git push branch_to_be_merged     # push the changes to remote
git checkout -b master           # the currently checked out branch is master
git branch                      # check I am on the branch I would like to merge later (it should now show *master)
git pull origin master           # apply the latest remote changes to my local master
git merge branch_to_be_merged    # merge  branch_to_be_merged to local master
git push master                 # publish the updates to master
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You Version with Comments

```sh
# you don't need to put 'origin'. If you have more than one remote, you can use 'git fetch --all'
git fetch origin                #make sure I am updated with latest remote changes
# the '-b' creates a new branch, this is not possible since the branch already exists. Remove '-b'
git checkout -b branch_to_be_merged   # the currently checked out branch is the one of interest
git branch                      # check I am on the branch I would like to merge later (it should now show *branch_to_be_merged)
# I would advice against doing this. Usually, 'pull' is used to update a
# local branch of the same name as the remote branch (it is a shorthand for
# 'git fetch && git merge origin/branch_name'.
# Secondly, 'pull' can be configured to use either 'merge' or 'rebase'
# so the behavior of this command depends on some configuration
git pull origin master           # apply the latest remote changes to my local branch_to_be_merged [I EXPECT CONFLICTS HERE]
# if you are merging the branch back to master you will probably delete
# it afterwards. Hence, you don't need to push it. You'll push your
# commits when you push the updated master branch
git push branch_to_be_merged     # push the changes to remote
# Again, no '-b' for existing branches
git checkout -b master           # the currently checked out branch is master
git branch                      # check I am on the branch I would like to merge later (it should now show *master)
# Simply use git pull, as this will automatically pull in the changes
# from the correct remote branch (so you cannot accidentally pull changes
# from a different branch)
git pull origin master           # apply the latest remote changes to my local master
git merge branch_to_be_merged    # merge  branch_to_be_merged to local master
git push master                 # publish the updates to master
```

### Short Solution

I would suggest the following commands:

```sh
git checkout master
# You don't need a git fetch at all, since pull does a fetch
git pull
git merge branch_to_be_merged # merge conflicts here
git push
# optionally delete the merged branch and its remote
git branch -d branch_to_be_merged
git push origin :branch_to_be_merged
```

Comment: ok this is clear. From your solution, there is no need to merge master with the branch, before merging the branch with master?what if the master has changed a lot since the branch was created?

Comment: If there are any merge conflicts when merging into `master`, you'll end up in a `merging` state on `master` with conflicting files marked by git. After resolving the conflicts `git add` those conflicting files and issue a `git commit`, thereby finishing the merge. To abort the (conflicting) merge you can use `git reset --hard` on `master` (caution with this command as it deletes any changes in you working directory). See "Basic Merge Conflicts" on https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Comment: BTW if you merged `master` into the branch then you'd have the same merge conflicts. The difference is that you end up with two `merge` commits, one for merging `master` into branch and a second for merging the branch into `master`, which is makes the history ugly (the files themselves would be in identical state).

Comment: in the end, it has been a complete disaster. Due to differences in .gitignore between branches. There were different but intersecting subsets of file which were untracked because .gitignored

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. To prevent problems like this it's advisable to  always have short running (a couple of days, at most one week) feature branches. If you need a long running feature branch it's best to regularly merge the `master` branch into your feature branch to always get the latest changes and not pile up potential merge conflicts.

Comment: we only learn trhough mistakes :) but  thanks, now I know how important is to keep feature branches short

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use the -b switch when checking out master, as the branch already exists

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Fetch everything from the remote master branch

   `git fetch origin master`
2. Merge your local branch with remote master

   `git merge origin/master`